# undefined reference to - c language standard 99 (CLion)

Tags: c, reference, clion

I have a problem referring to the method from the **"statistics.h"** header.

In the main.c I have a method to select the action from the menu (Win32API) and on case 2 I want to call the showStatistics() method but I get an error.

[undefined reference to `showStatistics'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WyYj.jpg)

**main.c:**

```
#include "statistics/statistics.h"
...
void Command(WPARAM wp, HWND hWnd) {
    switch (wp){
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            showStatistics();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

**statistics.c:**

```
#include "statistics.h"

void showStatistics() {
    FILE *file = openFile("..//assets//files//statistics.txt");
    if (file == NULL) {
        //TODO
    } else {
        //TODO
    }
    closeFile(file);
}
```

**statistics.h:**

```
#ifndef SNAKE_STATISTICS_H
#define SNAKE_STATISTICS_H

#include<stdio.h>

FILE* openFile(char *nameFile);
void closeFile(FILE* file);
void showStatistics();

#endif //SNAKE_STATISTICS_H
```

I am using IDE **CLion 2019.3.1**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Snake C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(Snake main.c)
```

I tried to look for solutions on Stack Overflow but I didn't find them.

I tried several settings set in CMake but without successfully.

I am writing an application in CLion for the first time.

Please help.

Comment: Try adding statistics.c in `add_executable` in the cmake file.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: The same problem after `add_executable(Snake main.c statistics/statistic.c)`? If so, try to Reset Cache and reload CMake project.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works.
My mistake. I am working on a larger project for the first time with CLion and I didn't know I could extend add_executable(). I added a new one each time and therefore it didn't work.
We can close the topic.